# how to backup MS OneNote notebooks (on Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, backup, microsoft-onenote

The instructions I have found for backing up OneNote notebooks don't seem to apply to the Mac version.  I just want to find my notebooks and copy them to a thumb drive.  Anyone know how?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free version only stores your files on the cloud. For any offline documents, OneNote stores all its files in the follow directory:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.onenote.mac/Data/Library/Application Support/Microsoft User Data/OneNote/
```

Comment: Is there any way how to read those files? I see only .bin binaries or some sqlite searches.